# File not being sent to Pen drive

Tags: windows-7, usb-drive

I have a 32Gb Pen Drive with me.
When i Try to send a file greater than 4GB it displays a message that the file is too large for the destination. Why does it displays this message?
How can i solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reformat it as NTFS instead of FAT.

And check out the other sites of "stackexchange", where such non-programming (!) questions are appropriate.

Comment: can you redirect me to which site you are talking about?

Comment: @vipin8169: You might like to have a look here: http://stackexchange.com/sites#

Comment: why it can't be sent on a FAT system???

Comment: Because that is the maximum file size for FAT32 filesystems ("640kb ought to be enough for anybody): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Allocation_Table